# How Do I Change WPF Listview SelectedItem Font Color With ItemSource Bound?

Tags: wpf, listview, fonts, listviewitem

I have WPF window containing a listview that has it's itemsource set to a collection of objects. When I access SelectedItem or SelectedItems[] or Items[], I get the my object back that's bound to that item, not the ListViewItem item itself. I have no idea how to select a row and change it's color since I can't access the item itself, like a winform listviewitem.

Comment: Protip:  You've added *waaayyy* too much xaml.  Edit your xaml to only highlight exactly what you're talking about.  For example, while it is amusing, the window Title won't get you a better answer.  Remove it and any other extraneous stuff.  Was going to do this for you, but frankly there is too much for me to bother cleaning it up.

Comment: Thanks. You have yourself a wonderful day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView derives from ItemsControl which exposes the ItemContainerGenerator property. This object allows you to map a bound entity to its ItemContainer (the item your are looking for) and back.

Comment: I would ask this as a seperate question. Follow up questions shouldnt be asked and answered in comments.